# Postgres's pg_basebackup never finishes creating backup

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to move files to another server to setup a slave.  I have a database on one Postgres Server and am attempting to create a file-based backup using pg_backup.  However, it never finishes executing the command.

Here is the output:

```
    /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_basebackup -U postgres -D - -P -Ft  > pg_backup.backup
    11247472/11247472 kB (100%), 1/1 tablespace
    NOTICE:  pg_stop_backup cleanup done, waiting for required WAL segments to be archived
    WARNING:  pg_stop_backup still waiting for all required WAL segments to be archived (60 seconds elapsed)
    HINT:  Check that your archive_command is executing properly.  pg_stop_backup can be         canceled safely, but the database backup will not be usable without all the WAL segments.
    WARNING:  pg_stop_backup still waiting for all required WAL segments to be archived (120 seconds elapsed)
    HINT:  Check that your archive_command is executing properly.  pg_stop_backup can be canceled safely, but the database backup will not be usable without all the WAL segments.
    WARNING:  pg_stop_backup still waiting for all required WAL segments to be archived (240 seconds elapsed)
    HINT:  Check that your archive_command is executing properly.  pg_stop_backup can be canceled safely, but the database backup will not be usable without all the WAL segments.
    WARNING:  pg_stop_backup still waiting for all required WAL segments to be archived (480 seconds elapsed)
    HINT:  Check that your archive_command is executing properly.  pg_stop_backup can be canceled safely, but the database backup will not be usable without all the WAL segments.
    WARNING:  pg_stop_backup still waiting for all required WAL segments to be archived (960 seconds elapsed)
    HINT:  Check that your archive_command is executing properly.  pg_stop_backup can be canceled safely, but the database backup will not be usable without all the WAL segments.
```

I've run this for hours on end, and it never finishes.  The database is about 11GB.

Any idea why this might fail and where I'd be able to find errors?

Comment: about archive command on the below : archive_command = 'cd .' is 'cd .' not 'cd.' , cd and dot between have space

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `archive_command`, which is configured in `postgresql.conf` is failing. We can't help you more — please provide more information, at least what is it's value?